# This application's bundle identifier does not match its code signing identifier

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9, code-signing

When I try to build and run the app on the device I get following error `App installation failed: This application's bundle identifier does not match its code signing identifier.`

I checked the signing certificates, bundle ids, provision profile, entitlements and everything is correct.

[image: Error message]

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end the error was caused by [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage).

After removing and rebuilding all frameworks it fixed the problem.

Comment: Also deleting all derived data.

Comment: Specifically, you should follow steps 4–6 of https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#if-youre-building-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos

Answer (score 13):

1. Go into `Building Phases`
2. Click the `+` sing and add script in `New Run Script Phase`
3. Add `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks` to the script box.
4. In `Input Files` add a line for each Carthage framework you're using in your app: `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/FrameworkName.framework`
5. If you're still having problems, also add this under `Output Files` for each framework: `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/FrameworkName.framework`

This process fixed it for me. It can be found under Carthage documentation. You can see this process here in items 4, 5, 6.
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#adding-frameworks-to-an-application

Comment: This must be selected answer!

Comment: Didn't think this would solve it for me, but it worked!

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, I had to set **framework's Product Bundle Identifier** to **anything with a dot**.

In my case it was because of framework, not Carthage's, but the one as target dependency in Workspace.

Before the fix Product Bundle Identifier was something like "FrameworkName", andXcode would automatically append some autogenerated ID, and Signing Identifier would become "FrameworkName-5555494493d11a8e5f473d1cb2a5d781973d171e".

When I set Product Bundle Identifier to something with dot, like "com.organization.frameworkName", Xcode stopped to auto-append anything, and everything works because ids match.

It seems that it wasn't an issue before Xcode 11 and Catalina. This debug was crazy.

Comment: Hey Could you please tell me where exactly you made changes?
Thanks

Comment: Problematic framework target -> Build Settings -> Product Bundle Identifier, like this ibb.co/zm3vr2c. How to find "Problematic framework target" depends on what you use to get 3-rd party dependencies, e.g. Cocoapods, Carthage...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom `.xcconfig` files?

Sometimes custom .xccofigs can override the default code-sign settings.

1) See if the project has a custom config by:
--- 1) Click on `project` whatever the project name is called in Xcode (usually at the top)

[image]

2) On the right you'll see your project settings. In here, you can set the identifier.. If not, then you're on the wrong view. This is what you should see:

[image]

3) Change the "bundle Identifier" to something to the effect of "com.yourcompany.yourAppName".
--- The com.yourcompany is your website domain name reversed.. Apple Recommend this.
--- After the com.yourcompany is the app name or "nickname' your give it so. com.yourcompany.myCoolApp would be the full identifier.

4) Once you've done this, make sure that under the "Build Settings" as below:

[image]

--- That your "Code Signing Identity" is set to whatever Identity you want. For Debugging on iOS or OSX you use "iPhone Developer: Your Name xxx" or "Mac Developer: Your Name xxx".

- Code signing resources path: reserved for advanced / command line tools
- Other Code Signing Flags: Not sure, never had to use this
- Provisioning Profile: IDEALLY set this to "Automatic" so Xcode handles the setting. Otherwise, when you've set a provisioning profile on the Member Centre, then specify it here (make sure you've installed it first though).

Answer (score 0):

in iTunes they changed it to have a flag for each role if he will have
Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
and by default its false.

All i had to do is to:

go to iTunesConnect -> Users and Access -> edit my role by checking the box of "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is only related to **CODE SIGNING**

But, the key point to note here is, if you are using XCode 11.x version.
Not only the code signing in your project, but we should check the code signing in Thirdparty SDKs or dependencies that we add to our project.

**Steps to verify the Code Signing of 3rd party SDks:**

1. Download the source code of framework you need
2. Open the .xcproj file from the source code using XCode 11.x
3. Go to Targets -> Signing & Capabilities -> Select all tab -> Bundle Identifier
   If you see any unevenness in the identifier like, identifier with 4 seperators (Eg: com.company.mac.app)

   Change it to **com.*** and enter.
4. Make sure your XCODE COMMAND LINE TOOLS is set with XCode 11.x
5. Now, use  below command to rebuild the SDK, with the changes done in above step-3

   ```
     carthage build --no-skip-current --cache-builds --platform iOS
   ```
6. Now copy the framework generated from, **carthage** folder of source code, and replace the existing SDK in your project.

Repeat the same for process for all the 3rd party SDKs, in your project.

**NOTE:** Make sure you marked all the 3rd party SDKs as **Embed & Sign** in

```
Targets => General => Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content
```

Comment: In my case it was a package with "Muon" as the bundle ID. Changing to "com.cocoapods.Muon" or anything with a dot resolved it

Answer (score -2):

Your app is signed by a Provisioning Profile, which in turn is linked to a Certificate (which can be either for development or distribution).

Now certificates have a Bundle ID, which can be:

1. A wildcard, such as "com.mydomain.*"
   OR
2. An explicit ID, such as "com.mydomain.myapp"

Either way, the bundle identifier of your app has to match the Bundle ID of the certificate tied to your provisioning profile.
A mismatch would trigger the error you're encountering.

Comment: Certificates do not have bundle ids.